# Checking buttons with same class but with specific values in python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click only those button with specific values (continue | check-again). I am trying to do this, but it is not working.

```
parent = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("button-next")
for each in parent:
    checkbutton = each.get_attribute("value")
    checkbutton = checkbutton.replace(" ", "")

    res = checkbutton.find("Continue")
    if res >= 0:
        each.click()
    else:
        res2 = checkbutton.find("check-again")
        if res2 >= 0:
            each.click()
```

Comment: Update the question with the HTML and indent your code trials

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `get_attribute()` function and then compare it.

```
for i in parent:
    if i.get_atributte('attribute_name') == 'Continue' or i.get_atributte('attribute_name') == 'check-again')
    each.click()
```

Comment: I have done this.

parent = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("button-next")<br/>
for each in parent:<br/>
checkbutton = each.get_attribute("value") <br/>checkbutton = checkbutton.replace(" ", "") <br/>

Comment: @PruthviRaj `parent = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("button-next")
for each in parent:
    checkbutton = each.get_attribute("value")
    if checkbutton == 'Continue' or checkbutton == 'check-again':
        each.click()`

Comment: I m getting some traceback error.
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
in each.click()
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: that means that the element can not be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a method
2. Write a dynamic xpath
3. Pass the value as parameter
4. Click on the button